# QR code and Barcode detection in Android using Kivy and OpenCV

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy

I'm trying to create an Android app that scans for QR codes and barcodes etc.I'm using Kivy and my program runs on Windows and MacOS smoothly.However when I build an APK using Buildozer my app loads and asks for camera permission but after that a white blank box appears instead of the camera.Here is my main.py, buildozer.spec and a screenshot of how app looks on an Android device.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SwapTransition
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy import platform
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import cv2

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'
        
        self.cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cam.set(3,1920)
        self.cam.set(4,1080)
        self.img=Image()
        self.fps = 60
        
        buttonCode = "Button\n    id:'exitButton'\n    text:'Exit'\n    font_size:'30sp'\n    size_hint:(1,.2)\n    background_color: (1,0,0,1)\n    on_press:app.stop()"
        self.exitButton = Builder.load_string(buttonCode)

        self.outputtext = Label(text='',font_size='75px',size_hint=(1,.2),color=(1,0,0,1))
        
        self.add_widget(self.img)
        self.add_widget(self.outputtext)
        self.add_widget(self.exitButton)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1.0/self.fps)
        
    def update(self,dt):
        if True:
            ret, frame = self.cam.read()
            
            if ret:
                buf1=cv2.flip(frame,0)
                buf=buf1.tobytes()
                image_texture=Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0]),colorfmt='bgr')
                image_texture.blit_buffer(buf,colorfmt='bgr',bufferfmt='ubyte')
                self.img.texture=image_texture
                
                barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)

                if barcodes == []:
                    scan_img = cv2.putText(frame, 'Scanning', (50, 75), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    scan_buf = cv2.flip(scan_img,0)
                    scan_buf = scan_buf.tobytes()
                    scan_texture = Texture.create(size=(scan_img.shape[1],scan_img.shape[0]),colorfmt='bgr')
                    scan_texture.blit_buffer(scan_buf,colorfmt='bgr',bufferfmt='ubyte')
                    self.img.texture=scan_texture

                    self.outputtext.text = str('')
                    self.outputtext.color = (1,0,0,1)

                else:
                    for barcode in barcodes:
                        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
                        rectangle_img = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(0, 255, 0), 7)
                        rectangle_buf = cv2.flip(rectangle_img,0)
                        rectangle_buf = rectangle_buf.tobytes()
                        rectangle_texture = Texture.create(size=(rectangle_img.shape[1],rectangle_img.shape[0]),colorfmt='bgr')
                        rectangle_texture.blit_buffer(rectangle_buf,colorfmt='bgr',bufferfmt='ubyte')
                        self.img.texture=rectangle_texture
                        
                        self.outputtext.text = str(barcode.data.decode("utf-8"))
                        self.outputtext.color = (0,1,0,1)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, check_permission, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA])

        self.sm=ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())
        self.mainsc=MainScreen()
        scrn=Screen(name='main')
        scrn.add_widget(self.mainsc)
        self.sm.add_widget(scrn)
        
        return self.sm
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_app=TestApp()
    main_app.run()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

***buildozer.spec***

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivy-garden,Pillow,pyzbar,opencv

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = CAMERA

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 33

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
android.minapi = 24

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 23b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 24
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbvbJ.png)

What might be my problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you check the reason for crashing in the app? through adb logcat? try using adb logcat by installing adb in you system and through usb debugging to be more specific type this in terminal/cmd after adding adb to path